# Applescript - Concurrently Rename and Copy multiple SD cards

Tags: applescript, automator

I've got a working Automator workflow which takes any single (one at a time) inserted LUMIX labelled SD card, reads a value from a text file on it and then renames the files on the card

```
 file= dayofmonth_variablefromtext_originalfilename.mp4
find /Volumes/LUMIX/DCIM/*/P*.MP4
then apply filename process to them
```

and copies them to an SSD.

It watches the /Volumes/ folder for a mount (LUMIX) then does its thing.
The advantage is that then we know which files are copied as they have been renamed.

However I now need this to work concurrently across multiple SD cards on the same machine - we are looking at a four card reader.
So while SD card 1 is copying, someone may insert another or more and we need them all to be processed in the same fashion with their unique identifier from the txt file on the card - or I guess the name of the SD card. We could rename the SD cards to have unique names, but in tests this did not seem to work and we need  8 or more SD cards for our team.

I cannot figure out how to achieve this in automator/applescript as the source folder /Volumes is a single watch point.

Essentially we are trying to avoid people waiting around till a slot is free for them to put the SD card into, with four, it can be slotted in and they can go (that is the idea)

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do that with simple AppleScript. You need to write a dedicated app.

Comment: I was afraid of that.